# Applications keep crashing

Tags: unity, bug-reporting

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 for a while now and I'm absolutely convinced I'll never downgrade to windows again.

Except for one problem I've been experiencing the last couple of days. Whenever I run different applications (Telegram, Firefox, Virtualbox) out of nowhere the applications do not respond anymore and I have to force shutdown my system. even ctrl + alt + f1 doesn't work.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the grub to max idle state 1 (or something). It did nothing so I reverted it.
- installing the 4.6 kernel. This is preventing unity to stop working so now I can just reboot normally when it happens. Other applications still crash though.

The problem isn't very consistent as it appears at random and at no given time. One time I have to reboot after 5 minutes and another time I can continue up to an hour.

In the syslog there is this:

```
rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="868" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

this line follows after a lot of "\00" with a red background repeating 10s to 100s of times. Also, not consistent. With a different pid everytime.

Hope this is enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say *applications do not respond anymore and I have to force shutdown my system*, do you mean that only the application is frozen, or you can't even open other programs or shut down the computer using the top panel indicator?

Comment: I can't click anything. The mouse moves but the keyboard and mouse clicks don't get registered. Nowhere. Until I installed kernel 4.6 Then I could use Unity but not the applications.